# JavaGlobal onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) not working in play framework java

Tags: java, request, http-status-code-404, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.1 and trying to implement Page for 404 requests.

For that I have created a errorPage.scala.html in my views and created a Global class inside            **MyProject->app->controller**

**Global.java**   ([Source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaGlobal))

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import play.libs.F.*;

import static play.mvc.Results.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
                views.html.errorPage.render(request.uri())
        ));
    }

}
```

But Its not working.When I am entering the wrong url it shows action not found page and display my routes file in browser.

Is there anything I am missing?

I have been trying other stack threds also but din't get any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Global class needs to be at the root package, i.e. within `app` and not wihtin the `controller` package. The link you posted documents that in the second sentence:

> Defining a Global object in your project allows you to handle global
>   settings for your application. **This object must be defined in the root package**.